# AWS SAM Function AutoPublishAlias "Invalid function version"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am using AWS SAM to deploy a Lambda function. I'am using the `AutoPublishAlias` property to automatically publish a new version when I deploy the function but I'm getting the following error: `Invalid function version 9. Function version 9 is already included in routing configuration. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 56b59a6b-6c57-434e-a505-ce7aa27c99b6)`. Every time I delete and create the stack the function gets created successfully, but when I try to update the stack I get the error. I'm also wondering why is the version number not starting from 1 after deleting the Lambda?

The Lambda definition:

```
ApiLambda:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  FunctionName: !Sub '${TagApplication}-${TagEnvironment}-api-lambda'
  CodeUri: ../build
  Handler: lambda.handler
  MemorySize: 256
  Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
  Runtime: nodejs10.x
  Timeout: 30
  AutoPublishAlias: 'live'
  ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
    ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: '1'
```

Screenshot of AWS Lambda console Alias menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to configure the `DeploymentPreference` property as well - see this link - https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/1296 and https://github.com/jcts3/sam-pc-experiment/blob/master/template.yaml#L22